# LiveCharts GeoMap WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, livecharts, geomap

I am trying to replicate this LiveCharts GeoMap in WPF but having an issue with the source file of my xml map :-
https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/GeoHeatMap

I can produce it fine under WinForms but need to create a working version under WPF, if anyone can assist or point me in the right direction, I’m sure it’s something obvious that I’m missing?

The error I get states that the source path for my xml file doesn’t exist, when it clearly does.

If I follow the example, I create a user control, copy in the xaml plus the code behind, as per the website, then in my main window xaml, make reference to the user control. It’s at this point that it can’t load my main window as it can’t find the source file that I have referenced in my user control. In winforms I can reference it using source=@“c:\temp\world.xml” in code behind but cant do that in the xaml either. Where am I going wrong!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems as if the NuGet package is outdated (2017).
Try to clone the LiveCharts repository and build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the XML file:

- set `Compile Action` to `none`

In the `Copy to directory`:

- set it to `Copy Always`

My Visual Studio is in Portuguese, but I think you'll get the idea.

If you're interested, there are detailed maps for each country/region; go to https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Maps.